# Update SQLite database when phone is asleep

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to update a SQLite database receiving a notification from Firebase. It works when the phone is awake (screen lock or unlock).

When the phone is asleep, the phone gets the notifications but the database is not updated.

How do I update my db (I don't really want to use Firebase Database though) ?

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Long lUserId = Long.parseLong(values.get("from_user"));
        Long lPopId = Long.parseLong(values.get("msg_id"));
        String lText = values.get("text");

        Intent service = new Intent(this, DatabaseUpdateService.class);
        service.putExtra("user", lUserId);
        service.putExtra("msg_id", lPopId);
        service.putExtra("text", lText);

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), service);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String mMessageTitle, String messageBody,  Intent service) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowConversationActivity.class);

        Bundle lExtra = service.getExtras();
        intent.putExtras(lExtra);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String lTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.message_from) + " " + mMessageTitle;

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.brand_icon)
                .setContentTitle(lTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        Log.d("DatabaseUpdateReceiver", "Starting service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        startWakefulService(this, service);
    }
}

public class DatabaseUpdateService extends IntentService {
    private long mUserId;
    private Intent mIntent;

    public DatabaseUpdateService() {
        super("DatabaseUpdateService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        mIntent = intent;

        ConversationAdapter lConversationAdapter = new ConversationAdapter();

        Bundle lExtras = intent.getExtras();
        long lPopId = lExtras.getLong("user");
        mUserId = lExtras.getLong("msg_id");
        String lText = lExtras.getString("text");

        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "--------------- > " + lText);
        lConversationAdapter.insertMessage(lPopId, mUserId, lText, (long) 0);
    }
}

public ConversationAdapter() {
    mDatabase = DataBaseOpenHelper.getInstance().getDatabase();
}
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

1: Check if you have provided WAKE_LOCK permission

2: ConversationAdapter constructor looks weird, no context to create?

Comment: Yes, I provided WAKE_LOCK permission. I have edited my question to update with the ConversationAdapter constructor.